# Если список упорядоченный по возрастанию, то ничего не выводить. Если не упорядоченный, то вывести первую строку которая ломает упорядоченность

Tags: java, list, arraylist

> Большая просьба, на основе моего решения, указать на ошибки. Так как в
>   некоторых моментах выводит верно, а в некоторых неверно. Точнее, если
>   ломающая строчка стоит в конце, то не выводится.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Solution {
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
  ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
  for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  {
    list.add(i, r.readLine());
  }

  for(int j = 0, k = 1; j < list.size() && k < list.size()-1; j++, k++)
  { 
      if(list.get(j).length() < list.get(k).length())
      {
       list.get(j + 1).length(); list.get(k + 1).length(); continue;
      }
   else 
    {
      System.out.println(list.get(k)); break;
    }
   }  
  }
 }
```

> > Попробовал решить таким способом, но выдает ошибку - выход за пределы массива: Exception in thread "main"
> >     java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 5 out of bounds for length
> >     5 Но если избавится от ошибки, не факт что код рабочий. Если не
> >     затруднит, оцените плз:

```
public class Solution2 {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
  ArrayList<String> oneList = new ArrayList<>();
  for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
  {
    oneList.add(i, r.readLine());
  }

  ArrayList<String> twoList = new ArrayList<>();

  for(int j = 0; j < oneList.size(); j++) { 
if(oneList.get(j).length() < oneList.get(j + 1).length()) {
        twoList.add(oneList.get(j));}
      else 
      {j++;}
  }
for(int j = 0; j < oneList.size(); j++){
  if(oneList.get(j) == twoList.get(j)){
    j++;
  }
  else{
    System.out.println(twoList.get(j)); break;
      }


  }
 }
}
```

> Вот вариант с правками. Но я сломал мозг с этими исключениями))) то
>   "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index
>   3 out of bounds for length 3" то "Exception in thread "main"
>   java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 2 out of bounds for length
>   2" то с другими цифрами. Никак не могу уловить, где именно они
>   создаются... Поменял еще вывод, вывести нужно № индекса.

```
public class Solution3 {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
  ArrayList<String> oneList = new ArrayList<>();
  ArrayList<String> twoList = new ArrayList<>();
  for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    oneList.add(i, r.readLine());
  }

  for(int j = 0; j < oneList.size()-1; j++) { 
if(oneList.get(j).length() < oneList.get(j + 1).length()) {
        twoList.add(oneList.get(j));
} else {
        continue;}
  }
for(int j = 0; j < oneList.size()-1; j++) {
  if(oneList.get(j).equals(twoList.get(j))) {
      continue;
   } else {
    System.out.println(twoList.indexOf(twoList.get(j+1))); break;
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: что именно не работает?

Comment: Например ничего не выводит при таких строках qwe
qwer
qwert
qweert
qw

Comment: А должно вывести qw

Comment: Точнее, если ломающая строчка стоит в конце, то не выводится. Но это надо смотреть и проверять и IDE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    ArrayList<String> mainMass = new ArrayList<>(5); //главный массив, который содержит то, что ввели
    ArrayList<String> extraMass = new ArrayList<>(1); //доп массив, содержит только один эдемент, есди есть нарушения
    boolean flag = false;

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) 
    {
        mainMass.add(reader.readLine());//считываем
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < mainMass.size() - 1; i++) //идем циклом по всему массиву
    { 
        if (mainMass.get(i).length() > mainMass.get(i + 1).length()) //сверяем длины строк
        {
            extraMass.add(mainMass.get(i + 1)); //получаем ту, которая лишняя
            flag = true;
            break; //если нашли, то выходим полность из цикла 
        }
    }
    if (flag) //сравнение, null - значит не прошло присвоение и все хорошо
    {
        System.out.println(extraMass.get(0)); //вывод
    }
```

Comment: теперь уж точно работает, проверил

Comment: Миш, спасибо огромное!. Наверно я достал этой задачей) Буду разбираться в решении, решение интересное - ( это я про flag (false, true)). Сам бы не смог решить так. По крайней мере на сегодняшнем знании java

Comment: Главное учиться. И практика) Все получиться. Если учишься в вузе - то больше мотивации, если нет, то ... тут надо самого себя заставлять

Answer (score 2):

Первое, код можно упростить:

```
for(int j = 0; j < list.size(); j++)
{ 
    if(list.get(j).length() < list.get(j + 1).length())
        {
            list.get(j + 1).length(); 
            list.get(j + 2).length();
            continue;
        }
        else 
        {
            System.out.println(list.get(k)); break;
        }  
}
```

Ваш код не работает, так как он не проверяет, как вы уже заметили, последнюю строчку, так как цикл туда не доходит.

Я бы на вашем месте, попробовал другой способ. Вначале - сортировка.

```
ArrayList newList = list;
Array.sort(newList);
```

Затем я бы пошел по листу, пока не найдем различие. Если различие найдено, то мы выводим его. Если различия нет (лист такой же), то ничего не выводиться.

Comment: если надо, могу и дальше код привести, но, думаю, вы стало понятно.

Comment: если не получиться, то сразу напиши

Comment: Конечно! Понял, вопрос изменили

Answer (score 2):

Теперь, в новом варианте кода появляется ошибка:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 5 out-of-bounds for length 5
```

Это значит о выходе за рамки массива/листа. Это происходит на сравнении:

```
if(oneList.get(j).length() < oneList.get(j + 1).length())
```

j идет от 0 до 4. (Размер равен пяти, результат - 0, 1, 2, 3, 4). Всего 5. На последнем этапе, когда j = 4, есть выход за рамки массива/листа. Так как вам не с чем сравнивать последний элемент, то следует остановить сравнение на предпоследнем элементе, то есть, в цикле for:

```
j < oneList.size() - 1;
```

Теперь следующее: у вас лист состоит не из int или double, он **String**. Это значит, что сравнивать с помощью **==** нельзя. Для строк, есть специальная функция equals(). Принцип работа:

```
if( myString1.equals(myString2))  
{  

}
```

Применяя это получаем:

```
if(oneList.get(j).equals(twoList.get(j)))
{
    j++;
}
```

Теперь третье :)
Я ввел :

> qwerty qwert qwer qwe qw

Мне выдает ошибку, т.к twoList вообще пустой!
Дальше, в этом куске кода есть снова ошибка:

```
for(int j = 0; j < oneList.size() - 1; j++) 
        { 
            if(oneList.get(j).length() < oneList.get(j + 1).length()) 
            {
                twoList.add(oneList.get(j));
            }
            else 
            {
                j++;
            }
        }
```

Тут уже проблема с логикой. Если предыдущая строка меньше, то мы добавляем ее в лист. Хорошо. Если нет, то увеличиваем j. Цикл заканчивается, и мы снова увеличивает j. В данном случае, *else* полностью лишний.

Пятое. И снова такой же недочет в этом куске:
Тут следует заменить j++, на оператор **continue**.

```
for(int j = 0; j < oneList.size(); j++)
        {
            if(oneList.get(j).equals(twoList.get(j)))
            {
                j++;
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println(twoList.get(j)); 
                break;
            }
        }
```

Если вам так уж хочется увеличивать j в самом коде, тогда из самого цикла следует ее убрать и получиться такое:

```
for(int j = 0; j < oneList.size();)
        {
            if(oneList.get(j).equals(twoList.get(j)))
            {
                j++;
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println(twoList.get(j)); 
                break;
            }
        }
```

> Теперь предлагаю вам пересмотреть ошибки, исправить их, продумать третью ошибку, исправит недочеты, перекусить и сесть за задачку с новыми силами!) Все мы учимся, где-то ошибаемся, но злому работодателю это не интересно... Когда напишите новый вариант кода, попробуйте сами различные тесты. И если что-то не получиться, о буду рад снова вам помочь!

Comment: Еще раз с кодом на вывод поигрался, совсем не верную инфо выводит

Answer (score 1):

Судя по новому коду, мало что понял. Эххх, так из меня учитель :)
И так... начнем сначала:
[Оператор contunie](http://proglang.su/java/operator-continue) прочитай все о нем, так как ты его используешь неправильно.
Второе: надо использовать ArrayList? Если нет, переходи на обычные массивы, они легче и понятнее. Готовое решение твоим путем:

```
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        String mainMass[] = new String[5]; //главный массив, который содержит то, что ввели
        String extraMass[] = new String[1]; //доп массив, содержит только один элемент, если есть нарушения

        for(int i = 0; i < mainMass.length; i++) 
        {
            mainMass[i] = reader.readLine(); //считываем
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < mainMass.length - 1; i++) //идем циклом по всему массиву
        { 
            if (mainMass[i].length() > mainMass[i + 1].length()) //сверяем длины строк
            {
                extraMass[0] = mainMass[i + 1]; //получаем ту, которая лишняя
                break; //если нашли, то выходим полность из цикла 
            }
        }
        if (extraMass[0] != null) //сравнение, null - значит не прошло присвоение и все хорошо
        {
            System.out.println(extraMass[0]); //вывод
        }
```

[Все о массивах](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/java/array.php)

Answer (score 1):

```
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    ArrayList<String> mainMass = new ArrayList<>(5); //главный массив, который содержит то, что ввели
    ArrayList<String> extraMass = new ArrayList<>(1); //доп массив, содержит только один эдемент, есди есть нарушения

    for(int i = 0; i < mainMass.size(); i++) 
    {
        mainMass.add(reader.readLine());//считываем
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < mainMass.size() - 1; i++) //идем циклом по всему массиву
    { 
        if (mainMass.get(i).length() > mainMass.get(i + 1).length()) //сверяем длины строк
        {
            extraMass.add(mainMass.get(i + 1)); //получаем ту, которая лишняя
            break; //если нашли, то выходим полность из цикла 
        }
    }
    if (extraMass.get(0) != null) //сравнение, null - значит не прошло присвоение и все хорошо
    {
        System.out.println(extraMass.get(0)); //вывод
    }
```

Comment: какая строчка непонятна?

Comment: С этим кодом как только нажимаю RUN , почему то сразу вылетает Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0. Насчет строчек -  Аа, тут вы сделали наоборот, ищите Неправильную строку. Действительно, так проще и мудрее!) Все строчки вроде понятны. Но единственное вот, исключения меня преследуют))

Comment: Сегодня я на онлайн IDE, может это имеет значение...

Comment: надо импортировать много вещей

Comment: import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

Comment: Библиотеки на месте. Сейчас проверил еще в Intellij IDEA, тоже самое. Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out-of-bounds for length 0

Comment: Да, это у меня косячок. Смотрю, что не так.